# Transferring a inputStream using Connect Direct in java

Tags: java, inputstream, mainframe, connect-direct

I am running a java batch job daily which will collect the data of certain details and it builds an inputStream. This stream is to be stored as a gdg in remote mainframe while the host server is UNIX. Previously we used *FTP*, but as it involves mainframe the new instructions suggest to use **Connect:Direct**.
 Is there any way we can transfer this data to create a new dataset into mainframe using **C:D**? Because everytime I run into other examples, it is always used in file transfer but I don't have a file instead I have inputStream variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through IBM Sterling Connect:Direct's Java application programming documentation yet? It should answer your questions, but please post a follow-up if not. Here's the direct link to those programming reference materials:

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sterling-connectdirect-application-interface-java-documentation

This reference material was published in 2011. The IBM Knowledge Center may contain some updates since Connect:Direct has evolved substantially since then, so I'd also look there, just in case.

However, I should raise a probable concern with the whole daily batch approach you describe. Will the end users be satisfied with only daily uploads of these data? That'll mean they're only ever seeing a historical state of the world as it existed many hours ago. One possible alternative pattern is to "de-batch" this data flow and shift it from a daily FTP (file transfer) (that presumably must complete processing within at least reasonably strict batch processing deadlines) to a continuous or near-continuous data upload stream of some kind (which may also offer more operational flexibility). There are a variety of ways to make that sort of shift, and I may be able to suggest some options with some more information about the data, the applications, and their usage contexts.